# Find $h'(0)$ given $h(z)=(e^{z\,g(z)})/(g^2(z)+1)$ and $h'(0)=2\,h(0)$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $g$ and $h$ two entire functions such that $$h(z)=\frac{e^{z\,g(z)}}{g^2(z)+1}$$ and $$h'(0)=2\,h(0)$$
>
> Find $h'(0)$

Here is my attempt below. Could someone check if it is correct? Many thanks.

The function $h$ is entire, so has no pole. It also has no zero since $e^{z\,g(z)}\gt0, \forall z\in \mathbb{C}$.

I also note that $h$ is of the form $h=e^{\phi}\,\psi$ with $ \phi(z)=z\,g(z)$ and $\psi=1/(g^2(z)+1)$.
The function $g$ is entire and so is $z\,g(z)$. Hence, $\psi$ and $h$ have the same number of poles and zeros, i.e. none. Hence $\log(h(z))$ is well defined.

Therefore, by the argument principle, $\oint_C{\frac{h'(z)}{h(z)}}=\log(h(z))=2\pi i\,(N-P)$ with $N=0$ and $P=0$ around an arbitrary closed path $C$ in $\mathbb{C}$.
So I get
$$\log(h(z))=z\,g(z)-\log(g^2(z)+1)=0$$ and for $z=0$
$$\log(g^2(0)+1)=0$$
Since $$h'(0)=2\,h(0)=1/(g^2(0)+1)$$ I obtain $$\log(2/h'(0))=0$$
That is, $h'(0)=2$.

Comment: Try $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{h(x+h)-h(x)}{h}\Rightarrow\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{h(0+h)-h(0)}{h}.$

Comment: @Theodoros Mpalis Thanks!

Comment: @Theodoros Mpalis so far I have not been able to see how your hint can lead to a solution.

Comment: my hint is wrong.

Comment: What else do you know about $g$ ?

Comment: All I know is that it is an entire function. Now, I am considering several approaches: using Cauchy-Riemann, using infinite products, using the argument principle, or trying to integrate around some path (Cauchy's differentiation formula).

Comment: Can't help you, try to delete that post and repost it again, to get some answers

Comment: I thought that was Calculus I . Repost it again to get some answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that there is a well defined branch of $\log h$, and this implies $\int_\gamma{h'(z)\over h(z)}\>dz=0$ for closed curves $\gamma$, but it does not imply $\log\bigl(h(z)\bigr)=0$, as claimed in your argument.

Since $h$ is entire and $e^{z g(z)}\ne0$ it follows that the entire function $g$ is $\ne\pm i$ for all $z\in{\mathbb C}$. From this we conclude by Picard's theorem that the function $g$ is in fact a constant. It follows that
$$h(z)={e^{gz}\over g^2+1},\qquad h'(z)=g h(z)\ ,$$
so that the equation $h'(0)=2h(0)$ leads to $g=2$, and this in turn gives
$$h'(0)=2h(0)=2\cdot {1\over 4+1}={2\over5}\ .$$

Comment: Thanks! I did not think of using Picard's little theorem. Could you tell me what is wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.